# Why does this happen: Connection closed by [my host IP] port 22

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

This on a Pi 4 running Buster.

I'm trying to ssh into a web host (HostGator) from this Pi.

I know ssh is working on the host because I can ssh from a Mac to HostGator without a password using rsa key pairs:

```
MrMuscle:~ mnewman$ ssh mgnewman@[my host]
Last login: Sat Aug 22 17:47:47 2020 from 1.20.171.54
mgnewman@[my host] [~]#
```

I know SSH is working on the Pi because I can ssh into the Mac without a password:

```
pi@raspsky:~/.ssh $ ssh mnewman@192.168.0.75
Last login: Sun Aug 23 06:11:14 2020 from 192.168.0.65.
MrMuscle:~ mnewman$
```

The host is in the known_hosts file:

```
pi@raspsky:~/.ssh $ ssh-keygen -F [my host]
# Host mgnewman.com found: line 1
```

This Pi's SD card was cloned from another Pi 4. On the new Pi I generated new public/private keys and new authorized_keys and known_hosts files.

Anyone have an idea as to how I can get this working?

tl;dr:

```
pi@raspsky:~/.ssh $ ssh mgnewman@[my host]
Connection closed by [my host IP] port 22
```

Here's what the debug output for the Pi looks like when the public key is sent to the host:

```
debug1: Offering public key: id_rsa RSA SHA256:4fUCtJQoMfxO/Za1goxtEjx5fyFq0tHgkus4jIhI7dE explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by [myhost IP] port 22
```

Here's what the same lines look like from the debugging output on the Mac:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/mnewman/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:2RluaUDGj/vNTMBi9DD1nEHT/Ets+qwbdvo+E7DsKS0
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/mnewman/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:2RluaUDGj/vNTMBi9DD1nEHT/Ets+qwbdvo+E7DsKS0
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to [myhost] ([my host IP]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
```

The entire verbose output:

````
pi@raspsky:~/.ssh $ ssh -vvv mgnewman@[my host]
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "[my host]" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to [my host] [[my host IP]] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/[my host].ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to [my host]:22 as 'mgnewman'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [my host]
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-```
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<8192<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 4114/8192
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zvfdYBMDWtOFnGjLosCOjO9MNKNaLHVcYNJSg6Wx428
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [my host]
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [my host IP]
debug1: Host '[my host]' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 4034/8192
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:4fUCtJQoMfxO/Za1goxtEjx5fyFq0tHgkus4jIhI7dE
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:4fUCtJQoMfxO/Za1goxtEjx5fyFq0tHgkus4jIhI7dE
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by [my host IP] port 22
````

Comment: You did install the new public key on your web host, right? (Just asking to make sure – it looks vaguely like you run out of tries on the server after the first key. Which is an … interesting configuration on part of your hoster, but nothing we can do anything about.)

Comment: Yep, it's there: `ssh-rsa <snip> pi@raspsky`

Comment: And the bit you've redacted really matches your id_rsa.pub, or whatever key you're using for this connection, yes?

Comment: Anything in your Pi client's ssh_config for this connection? Anything in the server's sshd/config that restricts inbound connections? If you `nc -vvv {gatorhost} 22` from the Pi do you get an SSH server protocol prompt?

Comment: @roaima - Yes they match

pi@raspsky:~/.ssh $ nc -vvv mgnewman.com 22
Connection to mgnewman.com 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3

What do I do next?

Comment: Please run ssh with the "-vv" flag to print debugging output. Then [edit] your question to include the debugging output.

Comment: And you populated authorized_keys on the host with the new key you generated on the Pi?

Comment: The full debug level 3 output is in the pastebin link in my original question. And, yes, I've verified that the authorized_keys file on the host includes the Pi public key.

Comment: Just to show that the Pi can do public key authorization, I logged on the Mac from the Pi:
 ```pi@raspsky:~/.ssh $ ssh mnewman@mrmuscle.local
Last login: Mon Aug 24 11:47:45 2020 from 192.168.0.65

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
MrMuscle:~ mnewman$```

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what happened here. I never could get rsa to work so I thought I'd try ecdsa. I generated a key pair and copied the public ecdsa key to the authorized_keys file on the host. I tried to ssh with that and it worked:

```
pi@raspsky:~/.ssh $ ssh -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa mgnewman@[myhost].com
Last login: Sun Aug 23 23:53:26 2020 from 1.20.171.54
mgnewman@[myhost].com [~]# exit
```

Then I tried rsa again. It also worked.

Did I somehow "fix" the authorized_keys file when I pasted the ecdsa key in? Maybe.